# Remove "linking against a dylib that is not safe for use in application extensions" warning in Xamarin iOS app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, dylib, suppress-warnings

I'm building an iOS app in Visual Studio for Mac.

I'm getting a bunch of `linking against a dylib that is not safe for use in application extensions` warnings. How can I remove them?

There seems to be a `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` setting in XCode for this, but I can't find this setting in VS for Mac.

There's a few libraries causing the warning. One is `GoogleToolboxForMac`, for instance.

Comment: Setting `Require Only App-Extension-Safe API` (`APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY`) to yes would cause the build to fail, you will need to modify the source to `#if` (that is the ObjC preprocessor, not the C# one ;-) to exclude any reference to items like SharedApplication, etc..